# OPTIONS is not allowed when I appen a custom header with fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, reactjs

I have a error 405 ('OPTIONS is not allowed') but never I send an options method when I try to connect to a web service, that error is only displayed when I add a new custom header in the request ('user-token'), I am using JavaScript fetch API, if I remove the custom header the web service respond with status 400, because it requires the user token for working, this is my code, I hope you can help me thank you.

```
var header = new Headers({
  'user-token': '196140da-451b-4ebd-a094-f94bf24eacdc',
});

var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: { key: 'value'},
    headers: header
}

fetch('http://service_url', req)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log('data', data))
.catch(err => console.log('err', err))
```

Comment: How is `reactjs` related to Question?

Comment: Cors settings allow for only headers the services defined. You sure the header you want is 'user-token' and not 'x-user-token' ?

Comment: CORS will bite you. If you do not own the server you are making a request to then your out of luck. Send the request to your domain then make the call from there.

Comment: So, it's necessary to have server in my domain, localhost ?

Answer (score 0):

[`body`](https://github.github.io/fetch/#request-body) does not expect a JavaScript object type. Use `URLSearchParams`,  `FormData` object, `TypedArray`, `DataView`, `Blob`, `JSON`.